# In a ring: $\, x^6 = x\,$ for all $x\ \Rightarrow\, x^2 = x\,$ for all $x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a ring: $\, x^6 = x\,$ for all $x\ \Rightarrow\, x^2 = x\,$ for all $x$

I found a short and interesting problem:

> Given a ring $(R, +, \cdot)$ and knowing that $x ^ 6 = x\ (\forall x\in R)$, prove that $x ^ 2 = x\ (\forall x \in R)$.

While it is short, I cannot figure out how to solve it. If it would be the reverse, then the solution were simple: $(x ^ 2) ^ 3 = x$.

Given this information, can be the problem be solved? If so, which is the simplest way to solve it?

Comment: You mean that this should hold for all $x$ in the ring, or just for some $x$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The problem says that for all.

Comment: @Mathmo123 The condition should be "$x^6 = x$ for all $x\in R$", but the "for all" was forgotten, I think.

Comment: @Mathmo123 The information about ring yes, but what I'm thinking at is could it be that it's referring to zero divisors only? I think that it would make it easier, however is there a possible solution without supposing that $x$ is a zero divisor?

Comment: Well, if $x$ is not a zero-divisor, then this says that $x^5 = 1$, so these are units, and the set of units has exponent $5$. It may be relevant that it is not possible for a ring to have precisely $5$ units (though I am not sure).

Comment: Is the assertion you're looking to prove known to be true ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the case where the ring has a unit (if not, then one could consider $R$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, but the details would change in that case).

Observe $2^6=2$ and $3^6=3$.  In other words, $64=2$ and $729=3$.  So $62=0$ and $726=0$.  Since $\gcd(62,726)=2$, it follows that $2=0$ (by repeated subtraction).

Therefore, we have a ring where $2=0$.  Now, consider $(x+1)^6=(x+1)$.  The LHS expands as 
$$
x^6+6x^5+15x^4+20x^3+15x^2+6x+1=x+1.
$$
Simplifying the even coefficients, it follows that 
$$
x^6+x^4+x^2+1=x+1.
$$
Since $x^6=x$, we know that $x^4+x^2=0$ or that $x^4=x^2$.  Since $x^4=x^2$, by multiplying by $x^2$, we have $x^6=x^4$ so $x^6=x^2$, but since $x^6=x$, $x=x^2$.

(There are a few places in this calculation, where one should be careful to make sure that I'm not cheating, but the ideas should work, at least in the case where $R$ has a unit.)

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks! I understood the way to solve it! However, can you please explain what *Simplifying the even coefficients* means? Why did the coefficients disappear? Also, why $x ^ 4 = x ^ 2$ instead of $x ^ 4 = - x ^ 2$?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Since $2=0$, we know that all even coefficients are $0$, for example $3x^2=x^2+2x^2=x^2$.  Since $2=0$, $1=-1$, so $x^2=-x^2$.

Comment: @Ionică It's clearer using the Bezout identity for gcds - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque That's also interesting. Thanks! (Y)

Comment: @Ionică It makes this problem trivial, reducing it to computing two gcds by the Euclidean algorithm (for integers and polynomials). Similar ideas work more generally, see the links in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/148346/242)

Answer (score 2):

See Theorem $2.6$ in the lecture notes [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ggim/W14-110BH.pdf). If $x^6=x$ for all $x$, then it is easy to show that $x^3+x^5=0$ for all $x$. Also $-x=(-x)^6=x^6=x$, so that $x=x^6=x\cdot x^5=x\cdot x^3=x^4$. A similar step shows that $x^2=x$ and that $R$ is commutative.

Answer (score 2):

Note $\,\ \overbrace{2^6\!-2}^{\large\color{#0a0}j} = 0 = \overbrace{3^6\!-3}^{\large\color{#0a0} k},\,$ so by Bezout their gcd $\,\color{#c00}2 = (\color{#0a0}{j,k}) = n\color{#0a0}j\!+\!m\color{#0a0}k = 0$.

Similarly $\ f(x) = x^6\!-x = 0 = f(x\!+\!1),\,$ so over $\,\color{#c00}{\Bbb F_2}\,$ their gcd $= x^2-x = 0.\ \ \bf\small QED$

Comment: Nice solution...

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks, These ideas are old, and they generalize widely. See the paper [cited here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/148346/242) for links to related literature.